# move_uploaded_file move cannot move to my directory

Tags: php

I use move_uploaded_file to upload my image to server. But when I check on my server, I found out that my image have move another file. I didn't spot any error on my code with online example. Can anyone guide me to solve this problem? TQ.

```
$file_path = realpath("../media/rewardreceipt/");
$img=$_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);

$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$img_name = uniqid();
$file_name = $img_name . '.jpeg';
$file = $file_path. '/' . $file_name;
$success = file_put_contents($file_path , $data);

if($success) {
     $arr = array('result' =>$file_name);
     echo json_encode($arr);
} else{
     $arr = array('result' =>'false');
     echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: What path does it go to & what path do you want it to go to?

Comment: First, the path that the image move to is the folder that i store all my php . Second,  the path i want to go is the $file_path that i declare in code.

Comment: I see some calls without error checking there. Also, unbalanced braces, undeclared variables and other missing info. You'll have to do better than this for a question that's considered on-topic.

Comment: Hi, unbalanced braces ald editand $img is the imageDataBase64 image that pass in using ajax.